# ES6 import throw Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following file:

**./js/ex.js**

```
export default class Sth {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Works');
  }
}

let sth = new Sth();
```

Adding it to my HTML file as follows:

```
<script type="module" src="js/ex.js"></script>
```

It works perfectly fine, so as I assume my browser supports ES6 syntax. (Chrome v61).

My app crashes when I try to import another file (AudioHandles.js) into ex.js:

**./js/AudioHandler.js**

```
export default class AudioHandler {
  constructor(piano) {
    //do sth
  }  
}
```

**./js/ex.js**

```
import AudioHandler from "./AudioHandler.js";

export default class Sth {
   constructor() {
   console.log('js module225');
 }
}

let sth = new Sth();
```

Trying to load this in Chrome says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at es.js:1
```

like Chrome has no support for import at all? Can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure `es.js:1` isn't a typo of `ex.js:1` or vice versa?

Comment: Try serving the file using some server, for example `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: Serve them via Express - var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./public')); where ./public consist of ./js folder. It is an issue?

Comment: Feels like this is a bug in chrome console, could you try to do something in the dom or probably show alert?